# query list options doesn't work

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2

i need to retrieve a specific messages from database

```
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angulrfire2/database';

export class homepage {
  constructor (private db:AngularFireDatabase){}
  getListMessages(myId, userToChatId,startAtNumber){
    return this.db.list(`users-messages/${myId}/${userToChatId}/messages`, (ref) => 
      ref.limitToLast(5).startAt(5).endAt(10)
    ).valueChanges().subscribe(res => console.log(res);
  }
}
```

this doesn't give me any data

messages database structure 
 [messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhOv7.png)

Comment: Need more detail about whats in the database etc.

Comment: this is the messages structure

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhOv7.png

Comment: Why add this `.startAt(5).endAt(10)` ? Try with a simple query without filters (like  `(ref) => ref`) and then add some filters.

Comment: please give me an example of filters